# How Aws glue scala save DyanamicFrame to athena table fastly

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, amazon-athena, aws-glue

I have to save AWS Glue data to Athena with minimum time.

I have saved AWS Glue data i.e. DynamicFrame to Athena table successfully. But for 17Gb table it takes around 19-20 Minutes. If number of DPU uses is 100, then I think it's too long time. Currently I am using method:

```
getCatalogSink( database : String,tableName : String,redshiftTmpDir : String = "",transformationContext : String = "") : DataSink
```

Is there any way to speed up the process? Or current required time is fine ?.

Thanks in advances.

Comment: Where is your source data stored? Is it S3? To make sure that the DPU are utilized fully it is important to understand spark parallelism.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - Source data located on s3.I think DPU is working fine,becoz when i am reducing number of DPU then execution time goes up.

Comment: Spark UI may give you some overview of the resource usage. I don't think you can open it for a running job, but you can get it using dev-endpoint - just need to open SOCKS5 proxy.